# Is it unethical to accidentally benefit from online material in a take-home exam?

Tags: ethics, cheating

Many years ago, as an undergraduate, I was taking a physics class which had a peculiar exam arrangement: on Tuesday, the professor gave us a take-home portion of the exam which would be submitted on Thursday, but on Thursday, there would also be an in-class portion of the exam with a different set of problems.

In my case, I remember working out the solution to a difficult problem on the take-home exam throughout Tuesday and Wednesday. I had a solution, but I was unsure whether it was correct. Some equations didn't seem to make sense. At the same time, I was also preparing myself for the exam on Thursday. As usual, I read the textbook, but I also was in the habit of consulting other websites to help me whenever the textbook wasn't enough.

While doing this, I accidentally stumbled upon a Wikipedia article which explained the solution of a similar problem to the one I was working on in the take-home exam. It was not the same problem, but the general method used was sufficiently similar so that I immediately realized that my approach to the problem on the take-home exam was probably correct.

Perhaps the most ethical thing to do at the time was to stop consulting the Wikipedia article immediately. I have to confess that I didn't do this exactly: I couldn't help but glance at it a few more times. Coming across that article made me confident in my approach to the take-home problem, and it drove me to scrutinize my previously written solution more deeply. This led me to discover a simple algebraic mistake which I had made in my own solution, after which my solution made sense and was surely correct. In the end, I never copied anything directly from the Wikipedia article, but I cannot deny that reading it helped me realize my own mistakes.

On Thursday I handed in my work on the take-home portion, and did well in the in-class portion as well. I never told the professor about the incident. Internally, I reasoned to myself that when I came across the Wikipedia article I was not trying to cheat on the take-home, but simply preparing for the in-class exam.

Years afterwards, however, I started to have doubts over what I did was completely ethical. I did not exactly cheat - in the sense of copying solutions from the Internet - but I was indeed "inspired" to become confident in my existing solution because of something I found on the Internet.

Was what I did dishonest? Unethical? Did it rise to the level of cheating that should have been disclosed to the professor? Or was it just a fortunate accident, the product of an odd exam arrangement?

(Note that the professor did not have a clear policy on consulting materials other than the official textbook from Tuesday-Thursday during the take home portion of the exam. While it was generally considered cheating to search out solutions on the Internet for specific problems on a take-home exam, I did not consider it unethical to look up online resources when studying a course and preparing for an in-class exam. In this case, I was doing the latter and accidentally stumbled upon material which was more similar to the former. The fact that there was a take home exam occuring right before an in-class exam resulted in a gray area.)

Comment: "the professor did not have a clear policy"  then your question does not have a clear answer.  Exam rules are the professor's responsibility.  Community opinion is not relevant.

Comment: I might add to the last comment that the question doesn't have a clear *objective* answer without an objective or explicit ethics policy.  You are welcome to be as ethical as you would like to be: my advice would be to allow the past to inform future behavior, including what goals you set (e.g. to perform a certain calculation from first principles, or even to know what first principles are), but not to mull over it.

Comment: It is astonishing how much people differ when it comes to righteousness and honesty.

Comment: The professor made a tactical error.  By having the take home portion before the in-class portion, he forced everyone into the same position you were in.   They had to study for the in-class exam, so they had to have access to course materials during the time they were supposed to be working the take-home test.  You don't have to feel guilty about being put in such a position.  The in-class test should have been first.

Comment: "Take home exam" is an oxymoron. Any "exam" which is not done in controlled conditions isn't worth calling an exam. (The take home task may be very useful as a *learning activity*, but that isn't the same thing as an exam!)

Comment: Often take home exams are administered at an educational stage where students progress from having relatively little academic responsibility to an enormous amount of it (when they start teaching.)  A take-home exam could either be interpreted as a sign of good faith in this transformation, or of trust in the student, or possibly as a kind of meta-test of the student's "academic accountability" (i.e. the ability of the student to prove to interested parties that the exam was self-administered without cheating.)

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist and TLDR, I agree that there might be no "objective" answer to the situation. Because it was a small college, the classes were small and the specific policies on collaboration and consulting outside material were informal and implicit. Even in-class exams were often not proctored. Students were expected to just "know" what was honest and what was not. But for some reason what happened during this exam keeps coming up and bothering my conscience once in a while, even though it has been almost a decade since it happened.

Comment: @B.Goddard I agree that the professor's choice to hold the take home before the in-class exam was the wrong one. It put all of us in this weird situation. It should have been reversed.

Comment: The way I read it is that you are concerned because you learned something on the internet. That seems absurd to me (which confirms @Alchimista's comment).

Comment: @alephzero: I've had good take-home exams. They need novel problems to work so you can't possibly look up the solutions.

Comment: Wait, I thought the whole point of take-home exams was that - just as in non-exam situations, everything is fair game except letting someone else actively do it for you

Comment: The point of going to school is to acquire knowledge and develop understanding. It might be called "take-home exam", but it's effectively just homework. What you did was (1) research/study for the real exam, and (2) you stumbled upon an example of a different problem that helped with your understanding, and prompted you to correct an algebraic mistake (*the* most irrelevant thing imaginable). Maybe the grade you got also accounts for your interest in the subject and your research skills - did you ever think of that? It's *absolutely absurd* to be concerned about this years later.

Comment: BTW, TLDR wrote "I might add to the last comment that the question doesn't have a clear *objective* answer without an objective or explicit ethics policy" - and if there was an explicit policy, and an objective (i.e. formal) answer, the key question that would come up is: is it form over substance? I second the "allow the past to inform future behavior" advice.

Comment: I see no ethical issue here. You were a student taking reasonable steps to inform yourself of something - unless you were subsequently elected head of the student union and called upon your fellow students to ransack the union building.

Comment: Exams that make you memorize something are not of much value as you will forget 99% of what you have studied unless repeated by use.  Knowing how to solve the problem with references is OK if the questions are challenging enough. Knowing where to find reference info to solve problems is part of your continued education.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I suggest that you don't lose a lot of sleep over something that happened several years ago. While you may have crossed a line, your description suggests it wasn't a bright line. Assuming your description is honest, you started out (probably) appropriately looking for alternate explanations of the material, not solutions to the problem at hand. But, rather than the internet it might just as well have been a different textbook.

But if it bothers you, then, assuming you are an academic, make sure that your own students get more explicit advice about what is and is not permitted.

It would have been better, of course, if you had pointed out the situation to the professor. But let the past be the past. Make the future better than the past if you are able.

Comment: 'assuming you are an academic, make sure that your own students get more explicit advice about what is and is not permitted'  And also think carefully about whether you're using the most appropriate modes of assessment for your intended learning outcomes.  I find it hard to imagine a learning outcome that is most appropriately assessed by a take-home exercise, and yet which requires that 'it was generally considered cheating to search out solutions on the Internet'.

Comment: _make sure that your own students get explicit advice about what is and is not permitted_. Also, make sure that there is some logic to your decisions about what is and is not permitted, as opposed to you setting up Kafkaesque trapdoors for your students to fall through.

Comment: @DanielHatton: I would presume that searching out solutions on the internet would only apply to a nearly exact duplicate. Something that would allow one to give the correct answer without understanding it.

Comment: @jmoreno Yes, that's what I thought.  If the intended learning outcome is to be able to reinvent from first principles an argument, derivation, etc. for which a near-exact duplicate is available on the internet, then I would suggest that a take-home exercise is not the most appropriate way to assess it; that particular learning outcome should instead be assessed through a closed-book, on-site exam.

Comment: ... on the other hand, if the intended learning outcome is to be able to state a particular result or principle, then there shouldn't be any problem with students searching out a solution on the internet, as long as they provide proper attribution and take due care over the quality of the internet source.

Answer (score 26):

It’s not unethical to *accidentally* benefit from anything, since the fact of such a thing happening is, as the word suggests, accidental. You didn’t mean to cheat, and it was the professor’s idiosyncratic testing policy that set up the perfect storm of circumstances that caused this “accident” to happen: note that the combination of a take-home exam and an in-class exam, and the way the two exams were scheduled, created a period of several days during which you were not allowed to search online for solutions to a specific set of problems, but during which you *were* allowed, and in fact incentivized, to look up general material related to the course. Hmm, I wonder what could go wrong with such an arrangement...?

TL;DR: **no**.

Answer (score 14):

A take-home test is not, as a more formal test or exam would be, strictly a test of knowledge.

It tests the synthesis of your knowledge and resourcefulness in a fixed time frame, in all respects no different than an essay.

Anyone who gave a test of that nature should expect the student to make use of all available resources and only plagiarism to be unethical.

Comment: Actually I question whether a "formal" test is a test of _knowledge_. Most are tests of fairly short term memory. A take-home test can get much deeper but it needs a different structure than a "formal" test to do so.

Answer (score 12):

Echoing @Buffy's remarks, but also paraphrasing/amplifying:

You were acting in good faith. That's the primary point. So don't worry about it.

Next: any system that tries to make rules to inhibit using more sources, looking around, comparing textbooks, etc., is seriously misguided. Yes, in my own earlier experiences, kids could get in trouble for reading ahead in their books! Could get in trouble for using ideas/methods from other sources!

In mathematics, and apparently in computer science, there is the idea that one should at least *attempt* to re-solve many basic, iconic issues for oneself, *before* seeing the highly refined iconic solution. Up to a point, if one has the time, obviously it's good to engage and appreciate the non-triviality before seeing a presumably masterful resolution.

"However", a person looking (e.g.) at math in a non-school-work setting, possibly skimming through various textbooks "for fun" (pre-internet!?!), could inadvertently see the iconic solution/discussion before being asked the iconic question in coursework. This happened to me a few times. My memory was good enough that I could more-or-less reproduce the iconic argument. I do not know what the grader thought.

Currently, in the grad-level math courses I teach, up front I emphasize that all the questions I'll ask them on homework and exams are important and iconic, and have been asked and discussed many times before. And while some engagement and reflection prior to seeing what other people have done is surely useful, there is a point of diminishing returns. And, rather than have people embrace crappy versions of iconic discussions, I do attempt to put on-line discussions that I at-least-currently think are better quality, if not perfect.

A thing that did not occur to me as a kid (and it was a different situation, internet-wise) was to explicitly acknowledge sources. This should have been emphasized then, but it was harder to "search" for things. Certainly this point must be made clearly nowadays.

Comment: You make good points. The problem that I was attempting to solve indeed turned out to be a variation on an "iconic" problem - one that was discussed and solved in many textbooks (but not in the textbook used in the class). So it was unsurprising that a similar problem showed up immediately when I visited the Wikipedia article on the topic.

Comment: Excellent points about the "idea" in math and CS. IME there is also a cultural difference in how lower level courses handle the material. In a grad class or upper-division undergraduate course, the instructor is *looking* for some level of independent exploration or creativity, even if minor. In a lower-division or high school course, the instructor is looking for specific mastery of *specific* curriculum items. In Calculus 1, students are expected to memorize a ton of 1700's-era formulas and use them. There's no room for squeezing in a neat, state-of-the-art formula one found in a journal.

Answer (score 9):

I would say that it's generally understood that on a take-home test you can use some external literature.

Typically with a take-home exam that takes a day or more, the expectation is that:

- Open-book: you're allowed to use the handbook for the course, as well as your lecture notes, and any recorded lectures and so forth.
- Extra literature: is allowed, although not necessary.
- No collaboration: you're not supposed to share your answers with, or receive answers from, other students.
- Your own work: don't ask other people, even people outside the course, for the solutions.
- Based on reasoning and application of what you've learned, not recalling facts. The problems may be harder and more diffuse than what you would get on an on-site closed-book exam.

There is probably some anecdotal exam that breaks each of these assumptions. As a teacher you'd do well to be explicit with your rules and expectations.

Using external literature to be inspired, to learn something that is helpful in the exam: fine. Adding a reference in your answers to where you found this useful literature: excellent. Rooting out an answer list on the internet: not okay.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to verify understanding of the material. If you gained that understanding as part of researching third-party sources, even if that happened during the exam, this is still in bounds. What would be wrong would be replacing understanding with regurgitation for convenience.

Answer (score 5):

> Unethical?

Given what the professor had directed you to do, I'd say no. I would even be of two minds regarding the unethicality of consulting a textbook during a take-home-only exam.

> Was what I did dishonest?

You were not maximally forthcoming - by your own standard. I guess that's what's bugging you, morally. By your professor's standard you were just fine.

> Did it rise to the level of cheating that should have been disclosed to the professor?

You're implicitly assuming your a no-good low-down sinner. Stop that.

Anyway, no. Also, if you had told your professor about this, I'm pretty certain he would have said something like "Well, you lucked out, that's life." Or maybe even "The fact that you noticed the problem were related and one was applicable to the other is an indication you have good command of the subject matter."

> Or was it just a fortunate accident, the product of an odd exam arrangement?

This.

But moreover - you're giving too much weight to what an exam means. It is not a fatal moral trial by the gods to determine your true nature or anything like that. Think about it more like a lottery where your skills bias the odds... I know that might sound a bit extreme, but you should really let this extreme view balance the other extreme. The exam grade is just a number, it's not paid for in blood and there isn't a one-true-grade for people.

Comment: +1: "Think about it more like a lottery where your skills bias the odds" - given that exam markers are human and fallible, I think this is actually quite a reasonable way to look at it. A similar way of looking at it might be that the variance in the mark you get for your exam script can be quite high (marking is not always that consistent), but your skills can give you some say over the mean. (From that perspective, someone marking your work is arguably then sampling from a Gaussian around the "real" mark.)

Comment: "your" ≠ "you're"

Comment: @StuartGolodetz: I actually wanted to suggest introducing a roll-of-dice component to people's grades in a course I was TAing, to emphasize this point.

Comment: Probabilistic events whose outcome we can bias with skills/training is a great way to look at nearly everything in life, really.

Comment: [The More I Practice The Luckier I Get](https://www.quoteikon.com/the-more-i-practice-the-luckier-i-get.html)

Answer (score 3):

The exam had no clear policy, so formally you did nothing wrong.

More in detail:

> I also was in the habit of consulting other websites to help me
> whenever the textbook wasn't enough.

You were consulting other sources because you felt the textbook was not enough. It all boils down to that. It is perfectly fine, as long as the reason was "the textbook was not enough".

It is very different than "consulting other sources to find the solution to my take-home exam".
If you did it because of that, you at least learned the skill "how to retrieve information" although it was not a skill you were supposed nor required to develop during that specific course. So instead of doubting the morality of your exams' attitude, you should question the degree you pursued :) !

Answer (score 1):

If you found how to solve the problem it is all ok. I see the problem only if someone else did the work for you. Why is that? The exam is there to prepare you for your future job and problems that you would face at your work.

Your boss will not tell you: please solve this but don't look at Wikipedia, do not use Google or some other textbooks. Your boss will just want the problem solved. You proved that you know how to find the solution if you don't know, and that is all there it is to it.

Comment: "The exam is there to prepare you for your future job" I think a Pandora vase has been opened here, I do not question you but I question this attitude to university ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment :)
I agree that there are always exceptions. Some people with a lot of money will spend money just to learn new things in Uni. But for most people it is just an investment, so they take student loan because they think that the degree will help them earn more money in the future. Anyways, I upvoted your answer as it is what I agree with. My answer was supposed to be a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that yet.